# Count if only last record of each group SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following data in SQL

| ID | date record | Team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa15 | 07/04/2022 | Alfa |
| aa15 | 07/04/2022 | Beta |
| aa15 | 07/04/2022 | Alfa |
| aa15 | 07/04/2022 | Alfa |
| aa15 | 10/04/1990 | Beta |
| aa15 | 10/04/1990 | Alfa |
| aa20 | 25/06/2022 | Alfa |
| aa20 | 25/06/2022 | Beta |
| aa20 | 11/04/1990 | Alfa |
| aa20 | 11/04/1990 | Beta |

I want to group by ID, count the number of entries per "Team", but only when the "date record" is the most recent.
The output would look like this:

| ID | date record | Team | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa15 | 07/04/2022 | Alfa | 3 |
| aa15 | 07/04/2022 | Beta | 1 |
| aa20 | 25/06/2022 | Alfa | 1 |
| aa20 | 25/06/2022 | Beta | 1 |

Any thoughts on how the query would be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this query

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT d.id AS ID,
    d.recent_date AS 'date record',
    d.team AS Team,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.id, t.team) AS Count
FROM (    
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT id,
        MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY id, team) AS recent_date,
        team
    FROM t
) d
JOIN t ON t.id = d.id AND t.date = d.recent_date AND t.team = d.team
```

Here we get the most recent date for each `team` per `id` value in the subquery and then count the self-joined rows.

Check [a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=927545f01b8b0c46e4d9c3eb357c216e)